# System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'WebProxyWrapper' to type 'System.Net.WebProxy'

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

In .Net 2.0 the following used to work:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
            WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy) WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

I'm using .Net 4.5 and now it is returning `IWebProxy` instead of `WebProxy`.

How can I cast it to be `WebProxy` instead of `IWebProxy`?

The reason that I want to do this is to check `proxy.Address.AbsoluteUri` and it isn't accessible using `IWebProxy`.

Comment: What about `proxy.GetProxy(httpWReq.Address).AbsoluteUri`?

Comment: that worked. Will you post the answer so I can award you? As a one-liner, the answer should be: WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(httpWReq.Address).AbsoluteUri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` has always returned a `IWebProxy`, but  the underlying concrete type has changed.  So instead of relying on the underlying type it's better to determine how to do the same thing via the interface if possible.  To that end the following should give you the `Uri` you want.

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(httpWReq.Address).AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: This does not always return the proxy. For example if using a windows service with a different account, this will not return the proxy.

Comment: @RobertSmith good to know before I try to find out if docs are right or not. The documentation says it gets proxy for the logged in user. Keywords Logged In User.